# How to write and use a node.js library that creates and uses a file in it's project root

Tags: npm, pnpm

I have a library called `lheadsup`, that needs to create a file and use that file as a lookup for further calls.

But the file needs to be created before using the library as part of a prebuild step, later the code assumes the file exists and reads that file.

How do I write and use such a library, I don't know when to call this script to create the file.

For example:

The application that uses this library is called `lheadsup-play`.

Now I don't want to publish this library to npm, I just want to clone the repository link locally and use it from application code.

Here's what my application code has this script:

`"copy_data": "mkdir data -p && cp ./node_modules/lheadsup/data/HandRanks.dat data/",`

So before using this library from the application code, I need to call this script to copy the file into my application folder so the library can access the file, so the code runs without errors.

Is there a better way to do this?

Finally I have to run a script to actually create the file sometime before I use this library as part of locally linking.